# problem with validating username and passsword on the login page

Tags: php, html

I am having a problem to get the user to validate the username and password from the login page.

I have tried different codes to try and resolve the issue.

```php
<!--
Here, we write code for login.
-->
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
include_once('link.php');
include_once('welcome.php');


    if (!session_id())session_start();

    $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root','usbw','pearl_bazaar');

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")


    {



        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Username']);
        $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['Password']); 

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$pwd'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        //$active = $row['active'];

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

        if($count == 1)
        {
            echo "you have logged successsfully";

            header("location: welcome.php");

        }

    else {

        echo "sorry incorrect username or password";

    }
    }       
?>
```

```html
<div id="frmRegistration">

<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="login_code.php">
    <h1>User Login</h1>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6"> 
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    </div>
  </div>


</form>
</div>
```

this is php code which I am using to access the data from the database which the user can validate their details with. I am able to retrieve the data from the database but only the validation isn't working.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193431/discussion-on-question-by-nadia-rashid-problem-with-validating-username-and-pass).

Answer (score -1):

Could it be because you're missing an opening curly bracket after your if statement `if (!session_id())session_start();`?

Because there is a closing one at the end of your code.

Correction would be: `if (!session_id()) { session_start();`

Comment: hello I have added the opening bracket into the code in the login_code.php but it still hasn't resolved the issue i'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

**The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string().**

Example

`

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

printf("Initial character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));

/* change character set to utf8 */
if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", mysqli_character_set_name($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

`

[charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

[real_escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Hope that would be helpful for you)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I will try the code.